# Skype video call taking a lot of battery power on mavericks

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery, skype

I have got mavericks 10.9.2 and latest Skype version 6.14(351) on a MBA 2013.
Whilst on a video call with one person only both cameras turned one and very good wifi signal Skype drained about 18% of the battery for 30 minutes. 
Also the laptop base became quite warm to even hot.

Is this normal and if not, how might I resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

Video processing is a CPU intensive task. 18% for 30 minutes is within normal operating times, as far as I can tell.

To save battery, consider lowering the brightness of your screen during a video call.

Comment: Screen brightness was quite low already. Although, you are saying 18% looks okay - that seems a bit too much. That amounts to roughly speaking 2.5Hrs for 100% charge.

Comment: Yes, it does appear large when you think of it as an overall figure. However, any claim of 12+ hours battery life is presupposed on the idea that you're only surfing the internet. A Skype Video Call (or even a FaceTime Video Call), is using up more CPU, as it has to both capture video and send it, and receive video and play it. It's like recording a video and playing a video at the same time.

Comment: Just trying to find out if anybody else got any better battery life and how ?

Comment: @ren You could also open Activity Monitor and see what CPU the Skype process is consuming. You could then quit it after 5 minutes of measured use and try using QuickTime player to make a 5 minute movie recording. Then you would have some hard data on CPU consumption to compare and possible change the quality settings on Skype to limit bandwidth or resolution and see if it affects the loading and power consumption.